# MySQL checking a range of characters with char_length() not giving results

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT FirstName
       , LastName
       , Phone
       , balance 
  FROM customers 
 WHERE balance > 0 
   AND phone != '' 
   AND char_length(phone) > 10 
   AND char_length(phone) < 11;
```

This gives not results back but if I do

```
SELECT FirstName
       , LastName
       , Phone
       , balance  
  FROM access_ayyaz_test.customers  
 WHERE balance > 0  
   AND phone != ''  
   AND char_length(phone) > 10;
```

or

```
SELECT FirstName
       , LastName
       , Phone
       , balance  
  FROM customers 
 WHERE balance > 0  
   AND phone != ''  
   AND char_length(phone) < 11;
```

They give results on their own but not together. How can I check the range then?

Comment: Pardon me, I mean to write 12

Comment: Those three are completely different queries...

Comment: You don't need `phone != ''` when you check for `> 10` because an empty string has a length of zero. Btw,  **>10 and <12** equals **11**

Answer (score 0):

The first query will not return anything because there is nothing can match this:

```
 AND char_length(phone) > 10 
 AND char_length(phone) < 11;
```

Try change your range a little bit:

```
SELECT FirstName
   , LastName
   , Phone
   , balance 
FROM customers 
WHERE balance > 0 
AND char_length(phone) >=10 
AND char_length(phone) <=11
```

Now you can have people with balance and proper phone number length.

Answer (score 0):

The queries

```
SELECT FirstName
       , LastName
       , Phone
       , balance  
  FROM access_ayyaz_test.customers  
 WHERE balance > 0  
   AND phone != ''  
   AND char_length(phone) > 10;
```

and

```
SELECT FirstName
       , LastName
       , Phone
       , balance  
  FROM customers 
 WHERE balance > 0  
   AND phone != ''  
   AND char_length(phone) < 11;
```

are checking for records with phone numbers with length greater than 10 and less than 11 respectively. Having these queries return values doesn't makes the condition `char_length(phone) > 10 AND char_length(phone) < 11` true.

There might be records where the length of phone number is 12, 13 or 14, which makes the condition `char_length(phone) > 10` true and return records satisfying that condition.

Likewise, there might be records where the length of phone number is anything less than 11 and makes the condition `char_length(phone) < 11` true and return records satisfying that condition.

**EDIT :** As per your comment, if you are looking for records with phone numbers of length between 10 and 12, you dont need two filters like

```
 AND char_length(phone) > 10 
 AND char_length(phone) < 12
```

as you can simple use `AND char_length(phone) = 11`.